# Deploy Angular 4 app in Weblogic server

Tags: angular, weblogic, weblogic12c, angular4-forms

Can anyone guid me how to deploy Angular 5 application in Weblogic server.

What I have tried.

1. I have build Angular app and added dist folder in root of webapp but its not working.  Error: 404
2. Just for testing I tried to deploy Angular app in Apache Tomcat. Error 404
3. I given the path of Index.html file. Error 404

Comment: May I know the reason for downvote ?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but what have you tried? This is a pretty broad question and shows you haven't done much research.

Comment: What error messages are you getting?

Comment: @WilliamHampshire I have updated the question.

Comment: @AkhileshMani can you explain how did you deploy the app in weblogic ? I didn't find any useful resources for that

Answer (score 0):

Weblogic is an oldie but a goody I guess. I did a project using Glassfish a year ago which is basically the same thing (I strongly recommend Payara just saying) and all we did was include Maven in the root of the angular project, wrap the necessary angular deployment files (index.html, js files etc..) in a war file, and simply deploy using the Weblogic/Glassfish type GUI. Not very hard stuff. The only hard part might be the deployment discriptor (web.xml) but all you need to do I think is tell Maven (or Gradle I guess) to ignore the web.xml Good Luck

**EDIT Try including the stacktraces along with the exact versions of stack along with Stack Overflow tags of all the items in your stack in your question **